# Invoke of ListView runs sub twice

Tags: vb.net, listview, invoke

I have been running the following code for a couple days fine but after doing some debugging yesterday I found out that the Sub has been firing twice.  Some background - This is a postage app that ships all of our packages. I neede to add a listview to the main form to show various rates that are returned from Easypost. When I first add the listview the app ran great from debug but after a compile it would completely hang after the list view was populated. So after a couple days of searching I added the invoke method which allowed the app GUI to continue after the listview was populated. So first I see if rates are returned and see that when it hits the lvRates.InvokeRequired it does the invoke and and then does the EasyPostGetServices a 2nd time which waste resources and creates to shipments at easypost loading the 2nd rates returned.

```
Private Sub GetEasyPostServices()


    EasyPostGetServices(dictEPFromAddress, dictEPToAddress, dictEPPackage)

    If EasyPostShipment.rates.Count > 0 Then
        If lvRates.InvokeRequired Then
            lvRates.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf GetEasyPostServices))
        Else
            For Each rate As Rate In EasyPostShipment.rates
                lvRates.Items.Add(New ListViewItem({rate.carrier, rate.rate, UCase(rate.service), rate.id}))
            Next
        End If

    Else
        MsgBox("Based on your inputs or preferences, no shipping services were available. Shipping services shown ignore your preferences. If none are shown, there are no shipping services available for this order.")
    End If
End Sub
```

My question is why is the code running twice and how do I prevent it from happening. I have moved the invoke around but everything else I try the GUI freezes when run from exe.

Comment: You can answer that for yourself: set a breakpoint and examine the call stack.  It looks like a DataGridView would be a better choice since A) you could work with a DataSource and B) you could store hieght, width etc as *numbers*

Comment: `GlobalVariables`?  That's a code smell.

Comment: You're telling a sub invoke itself, so it makes sense that it would be called twice doesn't it? If invoke is required, then GetEasyPostServices invokes another copy of itself on a different thread...hence two executions. The second execution, since it's running on a thread that doesn't need invoke, will drop down into the else block and finish.

Comment: Thanks soohooigan. I understand what you are saying but having a hard time understanding how to prevent it. As for Plutonix I could use a Datagrid but what does this help prevent the GUI from freezing. The package varibles do not need to be stored just returned rates form the easypost call which can be up to 30. I am very new to Mutlithreading and have not had to deal with it yet as I support legacy VB apps.

Comment: Do allow that you have more than just one dubious bit of code.  Constantly creating those same 2 dictionaries over and over, for instance.

Comment: `EasyPostGetServices(frAddress, toAddress, package)` is time consuming, I assume?  Does that code fill the `EasyPostShipment.rates` collection?

Comment: yes it does takes about 2-3  seconds. makes a call to easypost and returns matching rates which fill the listview so the shipper can pick the best rate or a specific rate.

Comment: This question isn't really answerable because there is obviously so much code that looks flawed.  The sheer number of global variables being used makes refactoring difficult.  You have spaghetti code.

Comment: I have removed all dictionaries and global variables and it runs the same. What I would like is how to fill the listview on its own thread so that the GUI thread would continue to run.

Comment: `If lvRates.InvokeRequired Then` should probably come first in the method.  The `EasyPostGetServices` call should then be part of that `else` block.

Comment: `What I would like is how to fill the listview on its own thread so that the GUI thread would continue to run.` Filling the ListView takes no time. It's the other stuff you are doing. You need to separate the UI and non-UI code and run them on appropriate threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was based on your original question. I've added a BackgroundWorker in a button click to cause GetEasyPostServices to start running on a non-UI thread. The crux here is how to properly invoke UI calls. The three methods at the bottom demonstrate that.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' this method is running on the UI thread as it handles a UI event
    Dim bw As New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker()
    AddHandler bw.DoWork, New System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(Sub(oo, ee) GetEasyPostServices())
    ' this call causes GetEasyPostServices to run on a non-UI thread
    bw.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub GetEasyPostServices()
    ' running on a non-UI thread. Any UI calls must be invoked
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
    Try
        Dim frAddress As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)() From {
            {"street1", "12345 Hill Dr"},
            {"street2", ""},
            {"city", "sometown"}}

        Dim toAddress As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)() From {
            {"street1", sAdd1},
            {"city", sCity},
            {"state", sRegion},
            {"verifications", New List(Of String)() From {"delivery"}}}

        Dim package As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
        If GlobalVariables.giLength > 0 Then
            package.Add("length", GlobalVariables.giLength.ToString)
            package.Add("width", GlobalVariables.giWidth.ToString)
            package.Add("height", GlobalVariables.giHeight.ToString)
            package.Add("weight", (sLbs * 16) + sOz)
        End If

        EasyPostGetServices(frAddress, toAddress, package)

        If EasyPostShipment.rates.Count > 0 Then
            ' hide the UI invocation logic in methods
            updateListView()
        Else
            MsgBox("Based on your inputs or preferences, no shipping services were available. Shipping services shown ignore your preferences. If none are shown, there are no shipping services available for this order.")
            clearAndFocusTbOrder()
        End If
    Finally
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
    End Try
End Sub

' these methods manage their own UI invocation.

Private Sub updateListView()
    If lvRates.InvokeRequired Then
        lvRates.Invoke(New Action(AddressOf updateListView))
    Else
        lvRates.Visible = True
        lvRates.Items.Clear()
        For Each rate As Rate In EasyPostShipment.rates
            lvRates.Items.Add(New ListViewItem({rate.carrier, rate.rate, UCase(rate.service), rate.id}))
        Next
        SortListView()
        lvRates.Items(0).Selected = True
        Button1.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SortListView()
    If lvRates.InvokeRequired Then
        lvRates.Invoke(New Action(AddressOf SortListView))
    Else
        lvRates.Sort()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub clearAndFocusTbOrder()
    If tbOrderID.InvokeRequired Then
        tbOrderID.Invoke(New Action(AddressOf clearAndFocusTbOrder))
    Else
        tbOrderID.Clear()
        tbOrderID.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

It's all about what, where, and why you invoke. In your example it wasn't clear if GetEasyPostServices started on the UI or not. I caused it not to so I could demonstrate how to properly invoke the UI calls. You then would need to invoke UI calls because it's not currently on the UI thread. That's the "why".

Also, it's key to run a minimal amount of code on the UI thread to prevent unnecessary processing and hanging the UI thread. Your original configuration ran all your code once, then ran it all *again*, on the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks larstech. dropped in djv and worked perfectly. This multithreading adds alot of extra work. Thanks guys